# get the child inside the parent javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

I am trying to show the child on hover over the parent or the child itself. so on hover over one div show the div inside it

**in other words on hover over the red container or blue div show the blue div**

```js
const bgsC = document.querySelectorAll('.cons');
const bgs = document.querySelectorAll('.bgs');

bgsC.forEach(bgc => {
  bgc.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    bgs.forEach(bg => {
      console.log(bg);
    })
  })
})
```

```css
.cons {
        width: 200px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        left: 30%;
        top: 200px;
    }
    .bgs {
        width: 200px;
        height: 70px;
        background-color: blue;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    p {
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        padding-top: .6rem;
    }
```

```html
<div class="cons">
    <div class="bgs">
        <p>hello 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cons">
    <div class="bgs">
        <p>hello 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cons">
    <div class="bgs">
        <p>hello 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and CSS to the snippet I made you

Comment: Also please look at delegation. And do you want to show ALL the bgs or only the one hovered?

Comment: I added the HTML code, on hover over one div show the div inside it

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you delegate from the nearest static container

change

```
const tgt = e.target.closest("div.bgs");
```

to

```
const tgt = e.target.closest("div.cons");
```

as necessary

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("div.bgs");
  if (tgt) console.log(tgt.querySelector("p").textContent);
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="cons">
    <div class="bgs">
      <p>hello 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cons">
    <div class="bgs">
      <p>hello 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cons">
    <div class="bgs">
      <p>hello 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```